# Momentjs alternates between 'a few seconds ago' and 'a minute ago' with a dynamic timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my web application, I have a status page that gets data from a server sent event every couple seconds. In that data there's a UTC timestamp that I am formatting with moment.js fromNow() so I know how long ago the data was pulled. It works fine until I try to update the timestamp dynamically with a setInterval().

The issue occurs when I switch to another tab for about a minute and the timestamp transition from 'a few seconds ago' to 'a minute ago' or more. The issue is that when I go back to the original tab, the timestamp will alternate between 'a few seconds ago' and 'a minute ago' every second or so.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('status.stream') }}");
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
            var errors = data.errors;
            console.error(errors)
        } else if (data.hasOwnProperty('result')) {
            var result = data.result;
            $.each(['critical', 'warning', 'unknown'], function(index, key) {
                var label = $('#'+key);
                if (result[key] > 0) {
                    label.text(result[key] + ' ' + key.toUpperCase());
                } else {
                    label.text('')
                }
            });
            if (result.hasOwnProperty('timestamp')) {
                var datetime = $('#datetime');
                var timestamp = result.timestamp;
                var update = function () {
                    var date = moment.utc(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').fromNow();
                    datetime.text(date)
                };
                update();
                setInterval(update, 1000)
            } else {
                console.error('Error getting timestamp!')
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Error getting data from the server!')
        }
    };
})
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably have multiple timers running, `setInterval(update, 1000)` starts a new sequence of timers each time it's called. You want one timer only, then just update the value of *timestamp* each time *source.onmessage* runs (i.e. remove the timer completely from *source.onmessage*, other than perhaps to initialise if if not already running).

Comment: @RobG Indeed, this is what I thought too. I had tried to move update() out already but still had issues. Your comment made me look into that again and I have found a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by moving update() out of source.onmessage as @RobG mentioned.

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var source = new EventSource("{{ url_for('status.stream') }}");
    var datetime = $('#datetime');
    var timestamp = null;
    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
            var errors = data.errors;
            console.error(errors)
        } else if (data.hasOwnProperty('result')) {
            var result = data.result;
            $.each(['critical', 'warning', 'unknown'], function(index, key) {
                var label = $('#'+key);
                if (result[key] > 0) {
                    label.text(result[key] + ' ' + key.toUpperCase())
                } else {
                    label.text('')
                }
            });
            if (result.hasOwnProperty('timestamp')) {
                timestamp = result.timestamp
            } else {
                console.error('Error getting timestamp!')
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Error getting data from the server!')
        }
    };
    var update = function () {
        if (!timestamp) {
            return false
        } else {
            var date = moment.utc(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').fromNow();
            datetime.text(date)
        }
    };
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000)
})
```